# Create RTF in Python, columns and bold text

Tags: python, rtf, formatted-text

I would like to be able to write a formatted text file, I don't need anything too fancy. Just be able to left/right align, **bold text**, *italicize*, etc. And rows and columns would be a nice option.

Is there a library for this?

As an example, I would like to generate an output file that has rows like:

```
DATE               TASKS                   HOURS        MILES

12-12-12          Task 1                  1.2 hrs     0.0 miles
                  Task 2

12-13-12          Task 1                  2.1 hrs     86.0 miles
```

I'm writing these lines from a list for each day that contains each field like so:

`['12-12-12', 'Task 1', 'Task 2', '1.2 hrs', '0.0 miles']`

I also have a header that goes above the table. Which I think limits me to text files, instead of an Excel Document.

I'm not committed to an rtf file, just to this rough format, so if you can think of another way to do this, that might be helpful as well.

I've found a couple of third party libraries for this online, like PyRTF, but it seems outdated, as it's last update was in May 2005.

The same goes for the questions I've found here on Stackoverflow. So, if anyone can find that this is a duplicate, let me know.

Comment: What about an excel file? is that an option for you? or just text files...

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that, I have a header that has to go above everything, is that something that can be done in Excel?

Comment: I think that you can .... I used this module once helped me a lot https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/ check it out.
You can write each row individualy

Comment: Will look into it now. Won't be able to try anything until I'm home, though. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are asking for a library which is rather off topic. But last time I found myself facing similar situation I ended using [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/). It has pretty nice documentation and according to its page on [PYthon Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab) it should be installable through  `easy_install reportlab` or `pip install reportlab`. But of course you will get hard to modify PDF instead of RTF ... You could also try to use [Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/) that generates formatted text in different formats

Comment: Personally, I'd use [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) for that. It's easy, can produce xls and xlsx files, and you can use cell styles easily to produce headers. It's a small, simple and easy to master library with no dependencies.

Comment: If you think something from 2005 is outdated, you'd better not look into the history of the RTF format...  Really, I think that's an unjustified criticism. If a package does what you need, doesn't matter if it hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: Well, my fear was that it wouldn't do what I need. Not being updated in 10 years, sometimes has that effect.